# Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

Tags: centos, yum, repository

When I say

```
# yum update
```

This is output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. $releasever is not a valid and current release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

## update

This is my base repo:

```
# cat CentOS-Base.repo 
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Comment: Just another question. Do you need to configure a proxy? If so, did you configure it?

Comment: No I didn't need////

Comment: Have you tried un-commenting `baseurl`, if not then, please try and show us the output. if you have `elink` or `link` then please try to open the link from command line change the line for example `releasever10`.

Comment: Yes I uncomment base url... the out put is: `Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again`

Comment: You have a working internet connection right. Check your `iptables -L` & show us the output. do `yum clean all` also

Comment: I have not iptables rules//// all policies are ACCEPT

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because the CentOS version you're using reached end-of-life, which means that no new updates will be released by Red Hat, so the tree has been moved to vault.centos.org, and the `baseurl=` links in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` files should refer to that link.

Please see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359927/112443